# Controllers in AngularJS is not works. I use $StateProvider. Project on ASP.NET-Core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I treid to make a contoller for each of my page but have a broblem. Mistakes in console, and the elements of controller don`t work on html page.

I use $stateProvider cod below is the cod of config, it`s work normal.

```
 var app = angular.module("appmyApp", ['ui.router']);

 app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

     // For any unmatched url, redirect to root
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

     $stateProvider
         .state('header', {
             abstract: true,
             templateUrl: '/app/pages/header.html'
         })

         .state('home', {
             url: '/',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/home.html',
             controller: 'HomeController'
         })



 }]);
```

When I add in the config the row - controller: 'HomeController'. I have a mistake in console.

```
angularjs.js:127 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=HomeController
at angularjs.js:7
at angularjs.js:97
at Object.<anonymous> (viewDirective.ts:410)
at angularjs.js:17
at Ba (angularjs.js:89)
at q (angularjs.js:73)
at g (angularjs.js:64)
at angularjs.js:64
at angularjs.js:69
at n (viewDirective.ts:328) "<div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">"
```

When I delete it, it is not any mostakes in console.

```
.state('home', {
             url: '/',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/home.html'
         })
```

In both case page opens good. Route is work. But controller is not work.

The cod of controller

```
var app = angular.module("appTradeRoom", []);
app.controller("HomeController", function ($scope) {
$scope.name = "Hello";
});
```

But on the view I have this.

http://prntscr.com/lzeyy5

Scripts home-controller.js I added in the head of home.html

```
<script src="/app/pages/home-controller.js"></script>
```

I added ng-controller="HomeController" to body in html page home.html but it does not work. What a problem. I Use last angularJS

Here is the reference on index.html

http://prntscr.com/lzf0cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
var app = angular.module("appTradeRoom", []);
app.controller("HomeController", function ($scope) {
```

To

```
var app = angular.module("appTradeRoom");
                                   // ^^ no dependencies
app.controller("HomeController", function ($scope) {
```

When there are no dependencies `angular.module()` will act as a getter of existing module, otherwise it will create a new one

Comment: Sirry but it didn`t help :(

Comment: Did you include the file also? I didn't see any controller scripts in images

Comment: Scripts home-controller.js I added in the head of home.html

Comment: Won't work that way. Scripts can't be in templates. Put in main index.html